# PushRow With Custom Object With Eureka Forms

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I'm having trouble to use a custom Object in Eureka Form, I'm trying to load the objects from a Rest Service, I'm using Alamofire to get the options, Im using row.options.append to fill the data, and when I select the cell I get an error assertion failed: Duplicate tag Building

Here is my class that conforms to the Equatable Protocol

```
class Building: Mappable, Equatable {
   var name_building: String?
   var id_building: Int?

   required init?(){
   }

   required init?(_ map: Map){   
   }

   func mapping(map: Map) {
      id_building <- map["id_building"]
      name_building <- map["name_building"]
   }
}

func == (lhs: Building, rhs: Building) -> Bool {
   return lhs.id_building == rhs.id_building
}
```

And here is the Form

```
import UIKit
import Eureka
import CoreLocation
import Alamofire
import KeychainAccess
import ObjectMapper
import SnapKit

class UserViewController: FormViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.title = "Perfil del Usuario"

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        form +++ Section("Datos Generales")
            <<< NameFloatLabelRow("kName") {
                $0.title = "Nombre"
            }
            <<< TextFloatLabelRow("kLastName") {
                $0.title = "Apellidos"
            }
            <<< TextFloatLabelRow("kPhone") {
                $0.title = "Teléfono"
            }
            <<< TextFloatLabelRow("kEmail") {
                $0.title = "Email"
                $0.disabled = true;
            }
            <<< SegmentedRow<String>("kGenre") {
                $0.title = "Genero"
                $0.options = ["Masculino", "Femenino"]
            }
            <<< CheckRow("kRider") {
                $0.title = "¿Estoy dispuesto a dar Aventones?"
                $0.value = true
            }

            +++ Section("Casa")
            <<< LocationRow("kHome"){
                $0.title = "Casa"
                $0.value = CLLocation(latitude: -34.91, longitude: -56.1646)
            }
            <<< TimeInlineRow("kHomeDepartureTime"){
                $0.title = "Hora de Salida"
                $0.value = NSDate()
            }
            +++ Section("Trabajo")
            <<< PushRow<Building>("kBuilding") {
                $0.title = "Edificio"
                $0.selectorTitle = "Donde Trabajas?"
            }
            <<< TimeInlineRow("kEnterTime"){
                $0.title = "Hora de Entrada"
                $0.value = NSDate()
            }
            <<< TimeInlineRow("kExitTime"){
                $0.title = "Hora de Salida"
                $0.value = NSDate()
            }
            +++ Section()
            <<< ButtonRow() { (row: ButtonRow) -> Void in
                row.title = "GUARDAR"
                }  .onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
                    print("Salvando Informacion")
                    let nameRow: NameFloatLabelRow! = self.form.rowByTag("kName")
                    let lastNameRow: TextFloatLabelRow! = self.form.rowByTag("kLastName")
                    let phoneRow: TextFloatLabelRow! = self.form.rowByTag("kPhone")
                    let emailRow: TextFloatLabelRow! = self.form.rowByTag("kEmail")
                    let genreRow: SegmentedRow<String>! = self.form.rowByTag("kGenre")
                    let riderRow: CheckRow! = self.form.rowByTag("kRider")
                    let locationRow: LocationRow! = self.form.rowByTag("kHome")
                    let homeDepartureTimeRow: TimeInlineRow! = self.form.rowByTag("kHomeDepartureTime")
                    let buildingRow: PushRow<Building>! = self.form.rowByTag("kBuilding")
                    let buildingEnterTimeRow: TimeInlineRow! = self.form.rowByTag("kEnterTime")
                    let buildingExitTimeRow: TimeInlineRow! = self.form.rowByTag("kExitTime")

                    let user = User()

                    user.email = emailRow.value
                    user.name = nameRow.value
                    user.lastName = lastNameRow.value
                    user.genre = genreRow.value
                    user.phone = phoneRow.value
                    user.id_type = riderRow.value == true ? 1 : 2
                    user.homeDepartureDate = homeDepartureTimeRow.value
                    user.jobEnterTime = buildingEnterTimeRow.value
                    user.jobExitTime = buildingExitTimeRow.value
                    user.id_building = 3

                    let location = locationRow.value! as CLLocation
                    user.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
                    user.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude

                    let JSONString = Mapper().toJSONString(user, prettyPrint: false)
                    let mappedObject = Mapper<User>().map(JSONString)


                    let request = "requesttoCreateUser"

                    Alamofire.request(.POST, request, parameters: Mapper().toJSON(user), encoding: .JSON)
                        .validate()
                        .responseJSON { response in
                            switch response.result {
                            case .Success:
                                print("Validation Successful")
                            case .Failure(let error):
                                print(error)
                            }
                    } 

                })

        self.getBuilding();

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func getBuilding(){
        let buildingRow: PushRow<Building>! = self.form.rowByTag("kBuilding")

        let request = "requestToGetBuildings"

        Alamofire.request(.GET, request).responseArray { (response: Response<[Building], NSError>) in

            let buildingsArray = response.result.value

            if let buildingsArray = buildingsArray {
                for building in buildingsArray {
                    buildingRow.options.append(building)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And It crashes here in the Eureka class BaseRow.swift

```
    final func wasAddedToFormInSection(section: Section) {
        self.section = section
        if let t = tag {
            assert(section.form?.rowsByTag[t] == nil, "Duplicate tag \(t)")
            self.section?.form?.rowsByTag[t] = self
            self.section?.form?.tagToValues[t] = baseValue as? AnyObject ?? NSNull()
        }
        addToRowObservers()
        evaluateHidden()
        evaluateDisabled()
    }
```

Comment: Normally this happens when you have another tag with `"kName"` or `"kLastName"` or "kBuilding" as the error says "Duplicate tag" can you check if you don´t add another cell with any of this names?

Comment: Nop, I don't have any duplicate tags, I've already check twice

Comment: can you post all your viewController code?

Comment: I've just updated the post to add the full code of the UserViewController

Comment: @Angel, any luck in solving this? Also, is it possible to use a custom type as options for `PushRow`? As in, an `NSManagedObject` subclass?

Comment: @shyam if you are still wondering  about this problem , i added an answer below credits for eureka members

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/552).

All you need to do is conform your model to `CustomStringConvertible` protocol.

> This is because the default implementation of SelectorViewController
>   uses String(option) as the tag for your PushRow rows

**So your class should look like this:**

```
class Building: Mappable, Equatable,CustomStringConvertible {
   var name_building: String?
   var id_building: Int?
   var description: String {

        return name_building
    }
   required init?(){
   }

   required init?(_ map: Map){   
   }

   func mapping(map: Map) {
      id_building <- map["id_building"]
      name_building <- map["name_building"]
   }
}

func == (lhs: Building, rhs: Building) -> Bool {
   return lhs.id_building == rhs.id_building
}
```